# Why Vert.x attaches 2 event loop per thread

Tags: java, vert.x

While going through vert.x Java devs guide I came across this fact that Vert.x attaches 2 event loop per CPU thread. How does this impacts performance as compared to 1 event loop per CPU thread?

Comment: Yeah, but this is a *Q&A* site.

Comment: Ok and I accidentally posted half question from my phone. Thanks for pointing out now please update the down votes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In documentation it says that Vert.x creates two event loops per **core** CPU thread i.e. 1 event loop per hyperthread.

Comment: That's not correct. I have 12C/24T machine, and vertx creates 48 eventloop threads (given I deploy sufficient verticles)

Answer (score 0):

This concept is called Multi-Reactor. Event Loop is an implementation of Reactor design patter. 
Event Loop needs to check for new events and dispatch them to corresponding handlers. If we use only 1 thread to consume all events we are not going to utilize  our hardware to max. In other languages and frameworks multiple thread/processes are used for this. Example: Node.js
This is why we have Multi-Reactor.

> In a standard reactor implementation there is a single event loop thread which runs around in a loop delivering all events to all handlers as they arrive.
>   The trouble with a single thread is it can only run on a single core at any one time, so if you want your single threaded reactor application (e.g. your Node.js application) to scale over your multi-core server you have to start up and manage many different processes.
>   Vert.x works differently here. Instead of a single event loop, each Vertx instance maintains several event loops. By default we choose the number based on the number of available cores on the machine, but this can be overridden.
>   This means a single Vertx process can scale across your server, unlike Node.js.
>   We call this pattern the Multi-Reactor Pattern to distinguish it from the single threaded reactor pattern.

[Full explanation](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_reactor_and_multi_reactor)

Comment: I understand the need of multiple thread loops for utilizing all CPU cores but I'm trying to understand the rationale behind having 2 event loop per CPU thread. Vert.x guide - " Every event loop is attached to a thread. By default Vert.x attaches 2 event loops per CPU core thread. The direct consequence is that a regular verticle always processes events on the same thread, so there is no need to use thread coordination mechanisms to manipulate a verticle state (e.g, Java class fields)."